# One-touch call option under Black-Scholes model

Tags: hedging, exotic-options

I know that a european call option can be valuated using the Black-Scholes formula, that is; $C_t(K)=BS(S_0,t,T,K,r)$, so if I have a one-touch call option given as

\begin{equation}
OTC_T(K)=(S_T-K)^+\chi_{[H_B\leq T]}=C_T(K)\chi_{[H_B\leq T]}
\end{equation}

where $\chi$ is the indicator function and $H_B$ is the first time when the underlying asset hits the barrier ($B>0$), is possible to define the value as in the previous, it means that at any time $t\in[0,T]$, we have

\begin{equation}
OTC_T(K)=BS(S_0,t,T,K,r)\chi_{[H_B\leq T]}
\end{equation}

If anyone has some information, or a counter-example is welcome, thank you very much for your time to read.

Comment: This forum does not support LaTeX - I'd suggest reposing on https://quant.stackexchange.com, which does (and is more fitting to your question).